# WP_Query get data if current date is in between dates

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to get all data that are in between 2 dates(start and end dates) based on the current date selected. For Example, the Selected Date is December 22, 2020, and on my Database, I have 2 start dates that are on December 22, 2020 to December 23, 2020, and there is 1 Start Date from December 21 and end date is December 23, 2020. Please Check below sample table.

The format stored in database is Ymd Ex. (20201222)

```
Current Date Selected: Dec 22, 2020
Data should be:

Start Date     | End Date
Dec. 21, 2020  | Dec 23, 2020
Dec. 22, 2020  | Dec 23, 2020
Dec. 22, 2020  | Dec 23, 2020
Total Value is 3
```

This is what I tried and it just gets only the current start date which is Dec 22, 2020, and not the Past dates like Dec. 21, 2020 to dec 23, 2020

```
$get_curr_glamps = 4; 
$start = '12/22/2020'; 
$end = '12/23/2020'; 
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'my-post-type',  
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'meta_query' => 
        array(
            array(
                'key' => 'check_in',
                'value' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start)),
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'date',
            ),  
            array(
                'key' => 'check_in',
                'value' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($end)),
                'compare' => '<',
                'type' => 'date',
            ),  
        ),
    
    );
    
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $arr_datas = array();
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        $check_in = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'check_in', true);
        $check_out = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'check_out', true);
        $fname = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'first_name', true);
        $get_status = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'payment_status', true);
    
        if($get_status != 'Cancel'){
            

                $number_glamps = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'number_of_glamps', true);     
                echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($fname.' ' .$number_glamps.'=='.date('Y-m-d', strtotime($check_in)));
                echo '</pre>';
            }
    endwhile;
    endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `'>='` and `'<='` use before and after in the array in `date_query`

```
    $get_curr_glamps = 4; 
    $start = '12/22/2020'; 
    $end = '12/23/2020'; 
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'my-post-type',  
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'date_query' => array(
               array(
                  'after'     => $start,
                  'before'    => $end,
                  'inclusive' => true,
          ),
        ),
     
   );

   $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Maybe this is possible on my end because I am using meta_query and the key are check_in and check_out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly then your meta query should look like this

```
$selectedDate = '22-12-2020'; # or whatever date format
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' =>
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'check_in',
                'value' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($selectedDate)),
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'DATE',
            ),
            array(
                 // you mentioned in a comment that the other meta_key is called "check_out"
                'key' => 'check_out',
                'value' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($selectedDate)),
                'compare' => '<=',
                'type' => 'DATE',
            ),
        ),
);
```

You want to get all the database entries that have a `check_in` date **before** the selected date and a `check_out` date **after** the selected date, so the selected date falls in between.

[WP Meta Query Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/)